# How to check if a filename is writeable in R?

Tags: r, file

How can I check if a specific filename can be written to?  Ideally I would like a function that works in the same way as file.exists() - it returns TRUE or FALSE, and doesn't spit out any errors whilst testing.

The ideal example:

```
filename = "X:/an/invalid/path"
file.writable(filename) # returns FALSE
```

I have not found a function that already does this, and can't really think about how to go about it.

One idea would be to try writing some junk data to `filename`, but I can't figure out the intricacies of using `try()` or `tryCatch()` to avoid lots of error messages coming out.  That also has the downside of overwriting the filename, which you might not want to happen.

Comment: There’s no good way of doing this: even if such a function existed (it doesn’t for good reason!) and you called it, the result of the function would be useless, because by the time you used the file, it might no longer be writable (for instance because it’s on a USB drive that the user removed). Just write to the file and handle errors.

Comment: In question about file access (or other interaction outside R) is nice to note if you looking for some system specific solution (windows/linux) or universal one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Edit

After looking at the function suggested by @Marek, it turns out there is already a function that does this in base called [`file.access`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.access.html).  If you read the warnings, they discuss the problems mentioned by @KonradRudolph in the comments (ie. file access can change).

So, all you need to do is

```
## Mode 2 for write permission
file.access(filename, mode=2)  # 0 success / -1 failure
```

Doing what you suggest (as @NickK pointed out this will overwrite the file!)

```
file.writable <- function(fname)
    tryCatch({
        suppressWarnings(write.table(1, fname))
    }, error=function(e) FALSE)

filename = "X:/an/invalid/path"
file.writable(filename)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: It's probably worth explicitly stating that your function will **overwrite** the file, which may not be desirable. For example, it might be intended to append to the existing file.

Comment: This did not work correctly for an Excel xlsx file on Windows 10. Still returned 0 (success) when file open in Excel and therefore unwritable.

Comment: @PeterVermont the function is working as intended. Office apps lock open files, which prevents other apps from writing to them.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi In Windows, open Excel files are not writable and will get a file permission error if you try to write. The function file.access incorrectly always returns 0 for open Excel Files. For Mac0S the method also returns 0 but the file appears to actually be writable. Excel will not detect that the file has been changed and this can leave to overwriting of the new contents.

Comment: @hong-ooi I know that Windows Office app locks open files but the issue here is that the R function does not detect that it is locked.

Answer (score 7):

There is `is.writable` function in Hadley's [assertthat package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=assertthat).

You could use it to write your function as:

```
file.writable <- function(path) {
    assertthat::is.string(path) &&
    file.exists(path) &&
    assertthat::is.writeable(path)
}
```